# Can I implement addition and subtraction in different operations using a MUX?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, alu, logisim

I'm building a 16-bit ALU that needs to be able to perform logical AND, OR, add, subtract and rotate one bit to the left.

I need to have addition and subtraction operate with different op codes through a mux. Right now I have my addition and subtraction going through the same output in my full adder.

Here's my 1-bit ALU slice. I'm wondering how I can alter it so I can have subtraction be it's own operation.

[image]

Comment: What are you confused about?

Comment: I want to be able to have a separate output going into my 8:1 mux for subtraction. Right now I just have addition and subtraction going into the same mux input, but I need to have addition be op code 010, which is what it is now, but I need subtraction to be op code 110.

Comment: Subtraction is just addition after taking the 2's complement of the subtrahend. And it looks like you already have all the pieces needed to implement 2's complement.

Comment: Just connect the ALU output to two MUX inputs. That's literally all.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to have addition be op code 010, which is what it is now, but I
> need subtraction to be op code 110

The output of the adder should split and go to both the '010' input *and* the '110' input. The op code value should also be used for additional logic gates that configure the adder for adding or subtracting.